# How to make a generic update function for a nested record in Elm

Tags: elm

In Elm I have a model with nested attributes like:

```
model =
  { name = ""
  , disruptedFields =
    { advertising =
      { name = "Advertising"
      , checked = False
      }
    , travel =
      { name = "Travel"
      , checked = False
      }
    , utilities =
      { name = "Utilities"
      , checked = False
      }
    }
  }
```

`disruptedFields` contains a list of values for checkboxes. When I click on the checkbox I send an update message to `UpdateDisruptedField`, which currently looks like:

```
UpdateDisruptedField value ->
  let
    fieldCollection = model.disruptedFields
    field = fieldCollection.advertising
  in
    { model | disruptedFields =
      { fieldCollection | advertising =
        { field | checked = (not value) }
      }
    }
```

My update function is hard-coded to `model.disruptedField.advertising` in the `field` and `advertising` variables. This is working for me, but I'm stuck making the function generic.

**How do I pass the record into UpdateDisruptedField so I can make it generic?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common problem for Elm apps with many input fields. There are two approaches for creating a generic update function to reduce code repetition.

1. Extend the message for update with identifier for an input and then add another level of switch with `case checkboxType of` and handle the update with all the nested Records. Every time you will add a new field in the model, you will have to extend the update with an extra branch for handling the update.
2. Re-structure your model with Dictionaries and handle the update in a proper generic way.

I prefer the second option, because updating nested Records is a chore.

Please consider the following example:

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (div, input, text, label)
import Html.App exposing (beginnerProgram)
import Html.Events exposing (onCheck)
import Html.Attributes exposing (type', checked)
import Dict


(=>) : a -> b -> ( a, b )
(=>) a b =
    ( a, b )


main =
    beginnerProgram { model = model, view = view, update = update }


model =
    { name = ""
    , disruptedFields =
        Dict.fromList
            [ "advertising"
                => { name = "Advertising"
                   , checked = False
                   }
            , "travel"
                => { name = "Travel"
                   , checked = False
                   }
            , "utilities"
                => { name = "Utilities"
                   , checked = False
                   }
            ]
    }


type Msg
    = Check String Bool


view model =
    let
        checkbox ( key, data ) =
            label []
                [ text data.name
                , input
                    [ type' "checkbox"
                    , checked data.checked
                    , onCheck (Check key)
                    ]
                    []
                ]
    in
        div []
            (model.disruptedFields
                |> Dict.toList
                |> List.map checkbox
            )


update msg model =
    case msg of
        Check checkboxId checked ->
            let
                updateRecord =
                    Maybe.map (\checkboxData -> { checkboxData | checked = checked })

                disruptedFieldsUpdated =
                    Dict.update checkboxId
                        updateRecord
                        model.disruptedFields
            in
                { model | disruptedFields = disruptedFieldsUpdated }
```

Please note, that I've been using `=>` operator to make Tuples look nicer.

`disruptedFields` is now a Dictionary, that uses `String` keys to identify every checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a [`Dict`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.0.0/Dict) instead of explicitly listing all the fields?