# How to upate a record that has another record within it?

Tags: elm

I have  a record :

```elm
type alias Point = {x : Int, y : Int}
```

I have another record like this :

```elm
type alias SuperPoint = {p : Point, z : Int}

p = Point 5 10
sp = SuperPoint p 15
```

Now if I need to update `SuperPoint.z` I can do this :

```elm
{sp | z = 20}
```

How do I update SuperPoint.Point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update an inner record in elm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958667/how-to-update-an-inner-record-in-elm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```elm
sp2 =
    let
        p2 = { p | x = 42 }
    in
        { sp | p = p2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have four ways to update:

- Two of them you can find below in code
- third is using [Monocle](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/arturopala/elm-monocle/latest).
- fourth: [Re-structure your model with Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545127/how-to-make-a-generic-update-function-for-a-nested-record-in-elm) and handle the update in a proper generic way
- A the end there is also a code which doesn't work, but could be useful, if that worked that way

Example in elm-0.18

```elm
import Html exposing (..)


model =
    { left = { x = 1 }
    }


updatedModel =
    let
        left =
            model.left

        newLeft =
            { left | x = 10 }
    in
        { model | left = newLeft }


updateLeftX x ({ left } as model) =
    { model | left = { left | x = x } }


updatedModel2 =
    updateLeftX 11 model


main =
    div []
        [ div [] [ text <| toString model ]
        , div [] [ text <| toString updatedModel ]
        , div [] [ text <| toString updatedModel2 ]
        ]
```

Examples from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elm-discuss/CH77QbLmSTk

```elm
-- nested record updates are not allowed
-- https://github.com/elm-lang/error-message-catalog/issues/159
   updatedModel3 =
        { model | left = { model.left | x = 12 } }

-- The .field shorthand does not for the update syntax
-- https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2015/11/06/functionally-updating-record-types-in-elm/
   updateInt : Int -> (data -> Int) -> data -> data
   updateInt val accessor data =
       { data | accessor = val }


   updatedModel4 =
       { model | left = updateInt 13 .x model.left }
```